# AIME 2001, Number Systems,

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** [AIME 2001] Call a positive integer $N$ a $7-10$ double if the digits of the base$-7$ representation of $N$ form a base$-10$ number that is twice $N$.For example, $51$ is a $7-10$ double because its base$-7$ representation is $102$. What is the largest $7-10$ double?

**My Attempt:** Let $a_0+a_17+....a_{k-1}7^{k-1}+a_k7^{k}$ be $7-10$ double. Then $$a_0+a_17+....a_{k-1}7^{k-1}+a_k7^{k}=2(a_0+a_110+....a_{k-1}10^{k-1}+a_k10^{k})$$
$$\Rightarrow a_0(1-2)+a_1(10-2*7)+....a_{k-1}(10^{k-1}-2*7^{k-1})+a_k(10^k-2*7^{k})=0$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: But their values must be the same right?

Comment: you have it backwards. It should be $2(a_0+a_17+....a_{k-1}7^{k-1}+a_k7^{k})=a_0+a_110+....a_{k-1}10^{k-1}+a_k10^{k}$.

Comment: You can find a solution here: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2001_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_8